# Angular: Type '"periodic-background-sync"' is not assignable to type 'PermissionName'

Tags: angular, typescript, service-worker

I try to activate a background-sync, but i run to error when I typing the code. 
Why can't find it?

Should i update something?

My code:

```
if ('periodicSync' in worker) {
    const status = await navigator.permissions.query({
       name: 'periodic-background-sync', //ERROR
    });
    // Periodic background sync can be used.
    if (status.state === 'granted') {
       const tags = await worker.periodicSync.getTags(); //ERROR
       if (!tags.includes('sendDbDatas')) {
          worker.periodicSync.register('sendDbDatas'); //ERROR
       }
    } else {
       // Periodic background sync cannot be used.
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be nice to update the question may be stackblitz or the code. right now we can only guess what are you doing and how (:

Comment: Sure :) Updated

Comment: `periodic-background-sync` is not one of the valid options for the [name enum](https://w3c.github.io/permissions/#enumdef-permissionname). More info on the usage of [this API is here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/query)

Comment: if you use VS Code you can hold command and click on the member (`name` in this case) to see it's definition

Comment: as Liam described earlier, name doesn't contains definition for periodic-background-sync. now, I try to create an interface for worker.periodicsync and cast permission.name tag to <any>

Comment: please don't forget to accept the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see typings doesn't allow the value 'periodic-background-sync'.

```
interface DevicePermissionDescriptor extends PermissionDescriptor {
    deviceId?: string;
    name: "camera" | "microphone" | "speaker";
}
```

as a workaround, you can use casting to any.

```
    const status = await navigator.permissions.query({
       name: <any>'periodic-background-sync'
    });
```

Looking into [Web Periodic Background Synchronization draft](http://%20https://wicg.github.io/background-sync/spec/PeriodicBackgroundSync-index.html) I would be brave enough to say this periodic sync is a modern feature that is not mature yet. No surprise typings are not aware of it.

Comment: I get permission.state == 'granted' but even if I call periodicSync.register(), it won't fire in service worker. If i use devtools (application/service worker/periodic sync) it fire.

Any idea?